# TypeError during normalization in sentimental analysis

Tags: python, normalization, sentiment-analysis, python-unicode

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import unicodedata
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

for date, row in df_stocks.T.iteritems():  
  print(df_stocks.loc[date, 'articles'])
    try:
        sentence = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', df_stocks.loc[date, 'articles'])
        ss = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
        df.at(date, 'compound', ss['compound'])
        df.at(date, 'neg', ss['neg'])
        df.at(date, 'neu', ss['neu'])
        df.at(date, 'pos', ss['pos'])
    except TypeError:
        print (df_stocks.loc[date, 'articles'])
        print ("date")
```

I have printed a small part of the `df_stock.loc[date,'articles']`

```
Trump Officially Wins Michigan Amid Calls for a Recount. World Trade Organization Rules Against Boeing Tax Break for New Jet. Donald Trump Faces Obstacles to Resuming Waterboarding. Flamingo Mating Rules: 1. Learn the Funky Chicken. Facebook Runs Up Against German Hate Speech Laws. What Changed, and Didn&#8217;t, After the 1988 Slaying of a Rain Forest Hero in Brazil. James C. Woolery Leaves Hudson Executive Capital Hedge Fund. Hampshire College Draws Protests Over Removal of U.S. Flag. China Takes a Chain Saw to a Center of Tibetan Buddhism. 5 Ways to Be a Better Tourist. How Tour Guides Abroad Learn to Cater to Exotic Americans. Local Transmission of Zika Virus Is Reported in Texas. Why Gunshot Victims Have Reason to Like the Affordable Care Act. Donald Trump’s Threat to Close Door Reopens Old Wounds in Cuba. Jimmy Carter: America Must Recognize Palestine. ‘Trump Effect’ Is Already Shaping Events Around the World. Delta Air Lines Bans Disruptive Donald Trump Supporter for Life. A Failed Bid for Time Inc. May Be Only a Start. C. Megan Urry, Peering Into Universe, Spots Bias on the Ground. A Forgotten Step in Saving African Wildlife: Protecting the Rangers. President Jacob Zuma of South Africa Faces Leadership Challenge. Belgium and the Netherlands Swap Land, and Remain Friends. Congress May Hold Key to Handling Trump’s Conflicts of Interest. Under Trump, Will NASA&#8217;s Space Science Include Planet Earth?. Summer Project Turns Into Leukemia Testing Breakthrough. Supreme Court Agenda in the Trump Era? A Justice Seems to Supply One. California Official Says Trump’s Claim of Voter Fraud Is ‘Absurd’. Daily Report: Uber Wants to Avoid ‘Transportation’ Label in Europe. Ukraine Has Made Great Progress, but We Need Our Allies. Thousands Flee Aleppo, Syria, as Government Forces Advance. Stuck at the Bottom in China. Suspect Is Killed in Attack at Ohio State University That Injured 11. A Baby Court Offers Hope for Families.
```

the stack trace is given below

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b6e18273a873> in <module>()
      6      # if type(df_stocks.loc[date, 'articles']).__name__ == 'str':
      7         sentence = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', df_stocks.loc[date, 'articles']).encode('ascii','ignore')
----> 8         ss = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
      9         df.at(date, 'compound', ss['compound'])
     10         df.at(date, 'neg', ss['neg'])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nltk/sentiment/vader.py in __init__(self, text)
    152     def __init__(self, text):
    153         if not isinstance(text, str):
--> 154             text = str(text.encode('utf-8'))
    155         self.text = text
    156         self.words_and_emoticons = self._words_and_emoticons()

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

From what i understand the issue seems to be the unicode.normalize function, but I can't figure out what the exactly is the issue.

Comment: It would help if you provided a stacktrace.

Comment: it executes the 2 print statements under the TypeError. No errors

Comment: Well, you have to explicitely print the traceback in the exception handler, or just remove the exception handler temporarily to get the stack trace.

Comment: I have included the stack trace, would be great if you could help me solve the issue @MrBeanBremen

Comment: I think I understood the issue (see answer), but I'm a bit confused: the error in the stacktrace is an `AttributeError`, while you are referring to a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*: I haven't worked with nltk and don't know the package, this is inferred from the stack trace and the `nltk` source code.

This looks like a bug in the `nltk` package itself.

The code in question:

```py
    if not isinstance(text, str):
        text = str(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

is clearly Python 2 code, that doesn't work in Python 3.

*For background*: in Python 2, `str` was basically a byte string, which could contain encoded unicode strings. To encode `unicode` strings, `encode` was used.
In Python 3, `str` is the unicode string and `bytes` is the byte string, so you can use `encode` on `str` to convert them to bytes, while this code tries the opposite.

I checked, and the code is still there in master (not changed since it was [written in  2015](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blame/8f0ad4bf77040de7efaa4c054755f56dcd713702/nltk/sentiment/vader.py)), so you could file an issue on their [GitHub site](https://github.com/nltk/nltk). I didn't find an issue for this problem, though there  is a [similar error](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1920) (actually the opposite - `'str' has no attribute 'decode'`, but the same problem with Python 2 code), and it is still unresolved.

To resolve this issue in your code, you should probably pass a `str` into the function as it cannot handle bytes. You could try something like this:

```py
    sentence = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', df_stocks.loc[date, 'articles'])
    if isinstance(sentence, bytes):
        sentence = sentence.decode('utf-8')  # this is assuming it is actually encoded as utf-8
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
```

I don't know if it handles `str` correctly either, but I would expect it - otherwise this would have popped up before.